# How to make token and refresh token at login on tymon JWT Auth

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

I do to make a JWT auth with Laravel and the Tymondesign jwt-auth, at login I need to make token and a refresh token but I found only how to make token. Someone can help me?

Answer (score -1):

Simply do $newToke = auth()->refresh()
Or
$newToken = Auth::guard()->refresh()

Check here for more details
https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/auth-guard/

Comment: He's asking for BOTH a token and a refresh token (a pair). refresh() invalidates the current one.